Problem with the pyverbatim and the bclogo environment
I'm using Latex to do my homework in programmation. So i use pythontex and especially the pyverbatim environment to got the python colors. My problem is visible on the next image:

i don't want to have this space between my code and the left border of the box. How could i fix it please ? I really want to keep pyverbatim and noindent, flushletf and minipage did work.
There my code:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Nécessaire pour inclure les images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{DarkRed}{HTML}{640b0b}



\presetkeys{bclogo}{ombre=true, epBord =2, couleur=pink!20, arrondi=0.1, barre=snake,
    tailleOndu=2,couleurBarre=DarkRed}{}


\newcommand\bcpy{\includegraphics[width =\logowidth]{the_logo.png}}
\begin{document}
\begin{bclogo}[logo=\bcpy,ombre=true, epBord =2, couleur=pink!20, arrondi=0.1, barre=snake, tailleOndu=2,couleurBarre=DarkRed]{Programme de la dichotomie:}
        \begin{pyverbatim}
            def dicho(f: 'function', t: float, a: int, b: int, eps: int)-> float:
                assert a != b
                assert f(a, t) * f(b, t) < 0
                
                while (b-a)/2> eps: 
                    x = (a + b) / 2
                    if f(x, t) > 0:
                        b = x
                    elif f(x, t)<0:
                        a = x
                    else:
                        return x
                return (a+b)/2
        \end{pyverbatim}
    \end{bclogo}
\end{document}

i would like to have something like this (with my bc logo set and my code obviously):

as i said, i tried minipage, flushleft and noindent nothing worked. I tried minted and listings, but it's not as good as pyverbatim.

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at our starter guide to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Sadly my french is not good enough for understanding the bclogo documentation, but from a quick look at the pictures, it seems to me that the code boxes with logos all share some space similar to yours. Maybe it's a feature not a bug?  A quick and supposedly quite dirty fix could be to put a negative vspace before \begin{pyverbatim}, like \vspace{-2em}.

Try without indenting your code or try gobble=auto

The code you show does not compile. \bcpy and the dark red colour aren't defined. Please test your code before posting.
